# A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the function ' ' because it has a return type of 'String'

Tags: flutter, return-type, non-nullable

I am following a flutter tutorial uses the following codes

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  late String _token;
  late DateTime _expiryDate;
  late String _userId;
  late Timer _authTimer;

  String get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    _token = null;
    _userId = null;
    _expiryDate = null;
    if (_authTimer != null) {
      _authTimer.cancel();
      _authTimer = null;
    }
    notifyListeners();
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // prefs.remove('userData');
    prefs.clear();
  }
}
```

But as I am using the new version of flutter it gives me the following errors:

```
A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the function 'token' because it has a return type of 'String'.
```

Or

```
A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Timer'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Timer'.
```

Also

```
A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DateTime'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'DateTime'.
```

I don't know how to fix this to make code run?

Comment: change `String get token` to `String? get token`

Comment: Sorry guys! I edited my question and added another part of code to show there are also another problems with `null` variables in new version of flutter.

Answer (score 2):

You should return the empty string `""` instead of Null.

You can't return Null for a function that has the return type string.

Comment: What can I do for the other code I recently added?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your declaration of method your return type is String and you returned Null instead of string. You should return empty string instead of Null.

```
String? get token {
   if (_expiryDate != null &&
       _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
       _token != null) {
    return _token;
   }
   return '';
}
```

for another one you should assign value based on your data type not null in every case. you should create nullable variables;

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String? _token;
  DateTime? _expiryDate;
  String? _userId;
  Timer? _authTimer;

Future<void> logout() async {
  _token = null;
  _userId = null;
  _expiryDate = null;
  if (_authTimer != null) {
    _authTimer?.cancel();
    _authTimer = null;
  }
  notifyListeners();
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // prefs.remove('userData');
  prefs.clear();
}
```

Comment: What can I do for the other code I recently added?

Comment: @ensan3kamel Please add declaration of variables in your question.

Comment: @ensan3kamel I have updated my answer. hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you Tushar. But why the keyword `late` I have used on my code doesn't work? What is the difference between using `late` or `?` ?

Comment: It seems your suggestion solved the problem but still there is one error as following:

`The method 'cancel' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').`

Comment: Also it seems it caused another error in the first function as following:

`A value of type 'String?' can't be returned from the function 'token' because it has a return type of 'String'.dartreturn_of_invalid_type
String? _token`

Comment: @ensan3kamel Please check. I have updated my answer. I hope this will solved your errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237622/discussion-between-tushar-moradiya-and-ensan3kamel).

Answer (score 0):

replace null with empty string in return type like this.

```
String get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return '';
  }
```

Comment: What can I do for the other code I recently added?

Answer (score 0):

From memory, try changing the function type to String? get token {...} that way you're telling dart that the function can return either a String or null.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).